# PHP Copy, file_get_contents not working when file is missing extension

Tags: php, copy, file-get-contents

Trying to copy an image from a Url that is missing the extension (.jpg, .png) to a remote server using PHP copy or `file_get_contents`

```
copy('https://appsdoc.wi.gov/public/secure/ImageServer?photoId=4010214&size=300', 'folder/file.jpg');
```

Copy example above doesn't do anything other than hang

`file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` do upload a file to the server but it's invalid, have tried different examples I've found on StackOverflow without luck, any ideas?

Comment: `curl -v 'https://appsdoc.wi.gov/public/secure/ImageServer?photoId=4010214&size=300'` and hitting the URL in the browser returns the same result, it hangs.  Is authentication required to access that resource?

Comment: Its just a photo https://appsdoc.wi.gov/public/secure/ImageServer?photoId=4010214&size=300

Comment: It doesn't even load in the browser for me.

Comment: It's a Governmet site it may only work within the USA, that may be why.

Comment: Possibly.  Regardless, the problem at the moment is the resource doesn't load.  For me, it may be because I am Canadian.  For you, it may be a different reason.  If this web service has documentation I recommend checking it to see if there are any auth requirements.  The resource you're after may be just an image, but access to it is being controlled.

Comment: I had no idea they would block other countries like that but it makes sense, testing on a USA server now. Its this https://www.google.com/search?q=wisconsin+sex+offender+registry